# Does LVM2 enable trimming of hard disks - does it really get zeroed?

Tags: linux, lvm, hard-disk, trim

I recently had to buy a new hard disk for my system. I'm running on a ssd, but for virtual machines i tend to use a hard disk. Since it had to be partitioned and formatted, i used LVM to add it to its own volume group and created one logical volume which was formatted with ext4.

Everything works fine. But when i trimmed my ssd with `fstrim` it took way too long. Turns out, that my hard disk was trimmed, too!

The filesystem is created with:

```
Default mount options:    journal_data_ordered user_xattr acl
Mount options:            barrier nodiscard utf8
```

I confirmed this later with the tool `blktrace` which reports trimming calls to this logical volume. Somewhere between the lines i even saw a DEL or DL with some nummeric address.

My question is:
Does enable LVM2 hard disks to be trimmed? Could it be, that the hard disk supports this? (IIRC it would have to, so that fstrim can work on it)

I'm old enough to know PIO. The first optimization was to eradicate the zeroing. I'd like to trim my hard disks, so that everything gets zeroed. I could disable trim when mounting and issue it with `fstrim`when the time fits.

Would be great, if it all works out as described.

Comment: Some HDDs do support TRIM: https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-purple-hdd/whitepaper-generic-benefit-for-hard-disk-drive.pdf

Comment: Looks like it's (useful) for [SMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording). Some companies (including Westerndigital) keep the fact that they are selling a SMR drive in the first place not very clear to the non business customer.

Comment: If someone uses this and confirmed that the specific HD area gets blanked. Let me now! :) I will search later to confirm this. I guess I may use dump or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like i was blinded by having the disk formated with LVM. `FSTRIM` mentioned only this disk. I didn't consider, that it was also a new drive and could have support for TRIM, like "Tom Yan" mentioned.

I thought about it, again. But this time i checked ith smartctl and it DOES have TRIM support. This is new to me. Although i still wonder, if it works correctly, this question should be answered.